# Id in domain model in case when natural id is unavailable

Tags: domain-driven-design, persistence

Let's say I have a domain model with no natural id.

```
class Offer {
  ClientId clientId;
  CompanyId companyId;
  OfferDetails details;
}
```

Offer is loaded from database by auto-generated key. Then it is modifed e.g. by calling a business method `accept`, `reject` or `renegotiate`. In order to persist the offer I must have this auto-generated key. How should I connect domain entity and id from db? Right now I have an `OfferId` class with db id and version (I use JPA to persist the aggregate). Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Right now I have an OfferId class with db id and version

The version shouldn't be part of the ID. The ID needs to be immutable.

There are several strategies to deal with ID generation, but here's the common ones:

- Use a GUID which relieves the need to hit a shared data store to generate the ID.
- Implement a `nextId(): OfferId` operation on your repository (implementation could use a DB sequence, etc.):

  ```
  Offer offer = new Offer(offerRepo.nextId(), ...);
  ```
- Allow the `Offer` class to be instantiated without an ID and configure your ORM to generate one. I'm not entirely sure about the JPA spec, but it seems that in Hibernate you can combine `@IdClass` and `@GenerateValue` annotations to map a DB-generated identity to a wrapping ID class. Have a look at [this test case](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/ceaeb81e3362ff187004ea3479b2afeeba5aa8a6/documentation/src/test/java/org/hibernate/userguide/mapping/identifier/IdClassGeneratedValueTest.java#L77).

Honestly I dislike delegating the identity assignation/generation to the ORM. If you want to generate the ID from the DB I would suggest the second approach I've described, with a method on the repository (or a dedicated service) that can return the next ID.

Comment: I like nextId approach. How would You suggest handling version?

Comment: @JulianRubin Just use an integer within `Offer` and let it be managed by the ORM. You can declare that field in a layer supertype, such as `Entity` rather than polluting all model classes. `Offer extends Entity`.